# Swagger UI not working for REST API (asp.net web api2) application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, swagger-2.0

I have asp.net mvc project with .NET Framework 4.7.2 and the same project contains asp.net web api2 controller in a separate folder : Controllers. The solution is legacy. The API are already in use in the PRODUCTION environment. Now I added the Swagger nuget package (Install-Package Swashbuckle -Version 5.6.0) to this existing project. Post that I see a SwaggerConfig.cs added to the App_Start folder of the Solution Explorer.

Here the asp.net mvc controllers are used by App1 pointing to the server: [www.app1.com](http://www.app1.com) and asp.net web api2 controllers are used by another frontend angular app: App2 pointing to the server : [www.app2.com](http://www.app2.com)

The complete deployment package for both App1 and App2 are hosted in IIS

Any request related to App1 is handled by [www.app1.com](http://www.app1.com) and any api request related to App2 (Angular frontend) is handled by App1 only using IIS Rewrite rules at App2 level which redirect any api request to App1 only.

Now in this case when I tried to navigate to [www.app1.com/swagger](http://www.app1.com/swagger) , I see it is loading the SwaggerUI for me, but when I tried to navigate to [www.app2.com/swagger](http://www.app2.com/swagger) it is not working and instead of that it is loading the Angular frontend application

Here goes the App1 and App2 at IIS level:

[image]

Can anyone help me here by providing their guidance to fix this issue?

Comment: In case of app2 what is your default application url ? it seems your angular application pointing to home. And yes if you enable url rewrite for the app2 then how come it  will point to swagger ? Instead of pointing to swagger it will redirect to app1

Comment: Thanks @RahulShukla for your response. I added rule to the existing URLRewrite rules present in the web.config file associated with App2 (Angular Front End) but it is not working and when I try to open the URL: www.app2.com/swagger , it defaults to www.app2.com/.